# Better ways to traverse a map of maps

Tags: algorithm, clojure, jvm, analytics

I'm doing some data analytics aggregations and here is my data structures:

```
{
12300 {
   views {
       page-1 {
          link-2  40
          link-6  9
       }
       page-7 {
          link-3  9
          link-11 8
       }
   }
   buttons {
       page-1 {
          link-22 2
       }
   }
}
34000      ....
}
```

Where 12300, 34000 are a time values.

What I want to do is to traverse that data structure and insert entries into a database, something like this:

```
insert into views (page, link, hits, time) values (page-1, link-2, 40, 12300)
insert into views (page, link, hits, time) values (page-1, link-6, 9, 12300)
```

What would be an idiomatic way to code that?  Am I complicating the data structure? do you suggest any better way to collect the data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you have a jdbc connection from clojure.java.jdbc, this should come close to what you want.

```
(jdbc/do-prepared "INSERT INTO views (page, link, hits, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
                  (for [[time data] m
                        [data-type page-data] data
                        [page links] page-data
                        [link hits] links]
                    [page link hits time]))
;; why aren't we using data-type, eg buttons?
```

### Edit for clarified problem

```
(let [m '{12300 {views {page-1 {link-2  40
                                link-6  9}
                        page-7 {link-3  9
                                link-11 8}}
                 buttons {page-1 {link-22 2}}}
          34000 {views {page-2 {link-2 5}}}}]
  (doseq [[table rows] (group-by :table (for [[time table] m
                                              [table-name page-data] table
                                              [page links] page-data
                                              [link hits] links]
                                          {:table table-name, :row [page link hits time]}))]
    (jdbc/do-prepared (format "INSERT INTO %s (page, link, hits, time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" table)
                      (map :row rows))))
```

Comment: Oh My God !! That is totally wicked !! Thanks. But didn't got your ;; comment.  Why not using doseq?

Comment: You only want to do one thing - an insert with multiple values. Why would you use doseq? My comment was to point out there is data in the map you're not using: `buttons` and `views` appear as keys, but do not appear in your insert statement.

Comment: buttons and views will be tables, so not all data are going to end in the same table. But now I can save to different tables with core.match or multimethods.

Comment: I added a version that deals with multiple tables the way you want. core.match and multimethods seem like driving really big round pegs into a square hole when you can just work with sequences.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution: take advantage of the fact that you are using maps of maps and use get-in, assoc-in functions to view/change data. See these for examples:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/get-in
http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/assoc-in

Advanced solution: use functional zippers. This allows you to traverse and change a tree-like structure in a functional manner.

An example here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Clojure_Programming/Examples/API_Examples/Advanced_Data_Structures#zipper

If you've got special data structures, not maps of maps, you can create a zipper yourself by simply implementing the 3 required methods. After that, all zipper functions will work on your data structure, too.